# WCF Client Certificate Validation + Windows Authentication

Tags: c#, wcf, authentication, ssl, iis

I've successfully created a WCF service which validates the incoming client certificate against the chain configured in IIS. However, as this is only a security mechanism to support authentication, I also need the Windows user calling my WCF service to handle authorization.

Normally when extracting the Windows User, you would do it like this

```
ServiceSecurityContext.Current.WindowsIdentity.Name
```

When my service is configured with security mode `TransportWithMessageCredentials`, the `PrimaryIdentity` in the `ServiceSecurityContext` will return the certificate's `SubjectName` and the `WindowsIdentity` will be empty.

To look at the client configuration, I've specified the `WsHttpBinding` like this

```
private static Binding GetHttpsBinding()
{
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Windows;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    return binding;
}
```

The client certificate is added like to the proxy client like this:

```
private static void ApplyClientCertificate(HelloServiceClient client)
{
    client.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(

        storeLocation: StoreLocation.CurrentUser,
        storeName: StoreName.My,
        findType: X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,
        findValue: "ClientCertificatesTest"

   );
}
```

Switching the two `ClientCredentialType` values so the binding looks like this

```
private static Binding GetHttpsBinding()
{
    var binding = new WSHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.TransportWithMessageCredential;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.Windows;

    return binding;
}
```

will work for extracting the Windows Credentials as described above, but when presenting an invalid certificate or no certificate at all are also accepted! Therefore the authentication requirement is not fulfilled. I can also add that when configured this way my implementation of `X509CertificateValidator` on the server-side will not trigger, hence my suspicion that the client certificate is not added.

Surely there must be some way to add a client certificate for authentication and add Windows Credentials to handle authorization in WCF? Is there any other way that I can add the certificate than adding it to the client credentials?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

So the answer to this question will be to create your own `CustomBinding` to get both Windows Credentails and Certificate validation.

Answer (score 0):

With Web Service references you could present both a client certificate and Windows authentication credentials, so it's strange that this isn't available out of the box for WCF?

Did you implement the custom binding or have any links of examples of getting this working?

UPDATE: here's the solution to create a custom binding to get both Windows Authentication and Client Certificates.
http://david-homer.blogspot.com/2021/05/using-net-wcf-basichttpbinding-to.html

Thanks,

Dave